# AMQP seems to block sinatra app when I try to use connection.close convention

Tags: ruby, sinatra, amqp

We have a very simple sinatra app that is receiving an incoming "order" from a POST request originating from a separate, Rails app. It needs to drop the order into RabbitMq, which we're doing with AMQP. It always works the first time, but the second time we try to place an order, we get an Errno::ECONNREFUSED error from rails until we restart the Sinatra app.

The thing is, I can make this problem go away by removing the `{ EventMachine.stop }` line, from the show_stopper proc. So it would appear that is interfering with Sinatra in some way...

So my questions- am I still safely cleaning up after the amqp connection when I don't stop the event machine? Can anyone illuminate why this would break the Sinatra app or point me towards some resources that might help explain what is happening here?

```
# Create a new Order
post '/api/v1/orders/new' do
  p "starting new order"
  log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  log.level = Logger::DEBUG

  # Adding the orders code here
  data = JSON.parse(params[:data])
  received_order = data["order"]

  Order.create(received_order) 
  log.debug "Received Order: #{received_order}"


  queue_name = "test"
  EventMachine.run do
    connection = AMQP.connect(:host => '127.0.0.1')
    puts "Connected to AMQP broker. Running #{AMQP::VERSION} version of the gem..."

    channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
    queue    = channel.queue(queue_name, {:durable => true, :exclusive => false, :auto_delete => false})
    exchange = channel.direct("")

    exchange.publish received_order.to_json, :routing_key => queue.name

    show_stopper = Proc.new {
      connection.close { EventMachine.stop }
    }

    EM.add_timer(2, show_stopper)
  end


  status 200
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't start and stop the EM reactor inside a sinatra route. Isn't it possible for you to use an EM based webserver like thin and simply connect, do your stuff and disconnect to/from AMQP in your route?

Comment: definitely possible- our goal here was to spin up a very lightweight service for managing communications from a few disparate apps. We chose sinatra because we thought that would work best.. Could you explain why you wouldnt use the EM reactor inside the route?

Comment: because if you're using Thin as app server you will stop the whole server. 1. Start/stop the connection, start the connection when you start the server and then start/stop channels instead. 2. Use the eventmachine AMQP lib if you're using Thin, but don't use an extra "EM.run" block. 3. Use Bunny if you're using any other app server.

Comment: @CarlHörberg bunny was a great sugestion, thanks!